# How to combine two buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, bass, bass.dll

There is `button_play` and `button_pause`. I want to combine them into one button. The first time the song is pressed, the song starts playing. The second press - pause. At the third press, the playback continues. I can not do it.

Please tell me, how I can combine them.

```
private void button_play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((list_catalog.Items.Count != 0) && (list_catalog.SelectedIndex != -1))
    {
        string current = Vars.Files[list_catalog.SelectedIndex];
        Vars.CurrentTrackNumber = list_catalog.SelectedIndex;
        BassLike.Play(current, BassLike.Volume);
        label_time1.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(BassLike.GetPosOfStream(BassLike.Stream)).ToString();
        label_time2.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(BassLike.GetTimeOfStream(BassLike.Stream)).ToString();
        xrewind.Maximum = BassLike.GetTimeOfStream(BassLike.Stream);
        xrewind.Value = BassLike.GetPosOfStream(BassLike.Stream);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void button_pause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BassLike.Pause();
}
```

Comment: so why can't you write your code using `1 Button` and then on the first button Click change the text to `'Paused` after clicking a second time check if the text of the button `.Contains("Paused")` then set back to "Start" and do some additional logic.. I don't see what the issue is here..? or learn to use booleans correctly..

Comment: Basically you want a way to check if the song is playing or not. Ideally you will have a method that can check the state of the song. Like `GetIsPlaying()` then you change your action based on the result of that function. Easy way is to track the state with a bool property `IsPlaying` and query that, each time you press the button you flip the property `IsPlaying = !IsPlaying;` and update the button text too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
private bool _isPlaying;

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!_isPlaying)
    {
        mediaThing.Play();
        button1.Text = "Pause";
    }
    else
    {
        mediaThing.Pause();
        button1.Text = "Play";
    }

    _isPlaying = !_isPlaying;
}
```

Comment: "Pause" not "Stop"

Comment: @musefan tnx... fixed it.

Comment: I do not quite understand your method. Can you change it based on my code?

Comment: @Gif It's kinda strange. This example is very basic and is way less difficult than your code. Did you write that code your self? It's better to implement it your self. My code only describes that with the use of a boolean field, you can switch between modes. play/pause

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a new Button object, and add the proper method for displaying the correct image. Something like this:

```
public class ButtonStateHandler:MonoBehaviour {
public boolean isClicked;
public Button myBtn;
public Sprite Play;
public Sprite Pause;

public void Click(){
    changeState();
}
private void changeState(){
    isClicked = !isClicked;
    if(isClicked)       myBtn.image.sprite = Play;
    else myBtn.image.sprite = Pause;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!